# Svelte label class gives me "A11y: A form label must be associated with a control."

Tags: javascript, typescript, label, svelte, svelte-component

So I'm building a drop-down select menu in Svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
    export let label: string;
    export let options: any[] = [1, 2, 41, 6];
    export let fullWidth: boolean = false;
</script>

<div class="select">
    <select class="select-text" required aria-label={label} class:full-width={fullWidth}>
        <option value="" disabled selected />
        {#each options as option}
            <option value="option">{option}</option>
        {/each}
    </select>
    <span class="select-highlight" />
    <span class="select-bar" />
    <label class="select-label">{label}</label>
</div>
```

It looks and works like I would expect, but `<label class="select-label">{label}</label>` has a yellow underline in VSCode that reads "A11y: A form label must be associated with a control.svelte(a11y-label-has-associated-control)".

The component itself appears and works totally fine but this is probably worth investigating in case it bites me in the butt later down the road. Anyone have any suggestions?

I'm also open to suggestions for the component itself aside from my current issue.

Comment: You can read up on accessibility e.g. [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility)

Answer (score 0):

As the warning states, labels should be associated with inputs. There are two primary ways of doing this:

- Wrap the input in a label

  ```html
  <label>
    <input type=checkbox />
    Thing
  </label>
  ```
- Using [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/for) and `id`

  ```html
  <input id=check type=checkbox />
  <label for=check >Thing</label>
  ```

There also are the attributes [`aria-label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label) and [`aria-labelledby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-labelledby) for other labeling scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

It's giving you a warning because every `<label>` element needs to be associated with a form control (`<input>`, `<select>`, etc). You can get this warning to go away by setting the `for` attribute on the label to the `id` of the `<select>`:

```svelte
<script lang="ts">
    export let label: string;
    export let options: any[] = [1, 2, 41, 6];
    export let fullWidth: boolean = false;
    export let id: string;
</script>

<div class="select">
    <select class="select-text" {id} required class:full-width={fullWidth}>
        <option value="" disabled selected />
        {#each options as option}
            <option value="option">{option}</option>
        {/each}
    </select>
    <span class="select-highlight" />
    <span class="select-bar" />
    <label class="select-label" for={id}>{label}</label>
</div>
```

Note that you can also remove the `aria-label` from the `<select>` -- since you're providing a name for the element with `<label>`, you no longer need `aria-label`.

Additional resources:

- [Svelte docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#accessibility-warnings-a11y-label-has-associated-control)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/HTML#meaningful_text_labels)